# How can I add a variable inside a variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Here's my code:

```
var realThing = defined here;
someHtml += "<img src='{0}' id='realThing'/> </a>".replace("{0}", something.something);
```

How can I put realThing, a variable inside someHtml which is another variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var realThing = defined here;
someHtml += "<img src='{0}' id='" + realThing + "'/> </a>".replace("{0}", something.something)
```

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
var Something = "words";
var SomeHTML = '<a href="/directory/' + Something + '/">Link</a>';
```

You must separate text in the SomeHTML variable with + sign in order to concatenate it.